# Opencv Build error with LINK1104

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am building opencv-2.4.9 in Windows with Visual Studio 2013.First I configure and generate with Cmake.

Then build using Visual Studio 2013.

I found error LNK1104 in building.

What could be wrong?

The errors are for all libraries, they can't be linked.

Errors are as follow.

```
Error   30  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_calib3d249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\ocl\LINK  opencv_ocl
Error   31  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_legacy249d.lib' E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\legacy\LINK   opencv_test_legacy
Error   32  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu249d.lib' E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\gpu\perf4au\LINK  gpu_perf4au
Error   33  error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  170 5   opencv_nonfree
Error   34  error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  170 5   opencv_superres
Error   35  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_features2d249d.lib' E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\imgproc\LINK  opencv_perf_imgproc
Error   36  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_superres249d.lib'   E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\superres\LINK opencv_test_superres
Error   37  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect249d.lib'  E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\apps\haartraining\LINK    opencv_haartraining
Error   38  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect249d.lib'  E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\apps\haartraining\LINK    opencv_createsamples
Error   39  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\videostab\LINK    opencv_videostab
Error   40  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_superres249d.lib'   E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\superres\LINK opencv_perf_superres
Error   41  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect249d.lib'  E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\apps\haartraining\LINK    opencv_performance
Error   42  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_nonfree249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\nonfree\LINK  opencv_test_nonfree
Error   43  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_nonfree249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\nonfree\LINK  opencv_perf_nonfree
Error   44  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_nonfree249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\stitching\LINK    opencv_stitching
Error   45  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_nonfree249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\contrib\LINK  opencv_contrib
Error   46  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect249d.lib'  E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\apps\traincascade\LINK    opencv_traincascade
Error   47  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_stitching249d.lib'  E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\stitching\LINK    opencv_test_stitching
Error   48  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_stitching249d.lib'  E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\stitching\LINK    opencv_perf_stitching
Error   49  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_contrib249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\contrib\LINK  opencv_test_contrib
Error   50  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_ocl249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\ocl\LINK  opencv_perf_ocl
Error   51  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_ocl249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\ocl\LINK  opencv_test_ocl
Error   52  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\gpu\LINK  opencv_perf_gpu
Error   53  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_gpu249d.lib'    E:\opencv-2.4.9\build\modules\gpu\LINK  opencv_test_gpu
```

Comment: Now I found the problem. For building in Windows, it is safe to download and build the Windows version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the configuration step.  Before pressing generate button, be sure that you specified the appropriate configurations. In this [link](http://audhootchavancv.blogspot.com.tr/2015/08/how-to-install-opencv-30-and.html) , you can find an example of configuration to build opencv. Especially, take attention to 'WITH' segments.